# use for-loop through couples data.frame and apply function on them

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I want to loop through couples variable, there's something wrong but I can't figure it out.

```
# education1,...trade1 are similar dataframe
# for example:
> education1
year   country  BeiJing   TianJin     HeBei    ShanXi  NeiMengGu  LiaoNing     JiLin       HeiLongJiang  ShangHai
1  2001  52920.47 1036.893  1975.061  1881.812  449.3267   198.8855  1551.363  361.7969     401.1776  3607.987
2  2002  65876.57 1367.643  2256.970  2329.523  648.7870   281.0629  1836.396  480.6575     499.5945  4228.255
3  2003  89227.20 1305.015  2841.379  4097.265  917.7571   497.8728  2560.662  616.4603     638.3171  5536.286
4  2004  92656.06 2282.841  3655.690  3853.677  416.8565   279.0049  2063.824  478.8450    -935.1350  7194.885
5  2005 167115.37 3464.530  4378.463  6926.047 2344.5597  1428.8180  5162.982 1258.4900    1108.1822  9837.540
6  2006 218827.79 4576.187  4971.573  9220.174 2918.0159  2340.6012  7613.243 1820.5200    1237.1062 11767.648

# I want to change all of dataframe's colname, say:
name <- c('a','b','c','d',.....)

for (x in vector(education1,fir1,inflation1,lq1,nonstatein1,patent1,tax1,trade1)) {
    names(x) <- name  # name is an array of rowname which defined before the loop
}
```

when run the code above it show no error but the rowname of each dataframe didn't change.

Comment: It is obvious you are coming from a C background (or something similar), but this is not how you do things in R. Please explain in words what are you trying to achieve and provide an example data set and the desired output

Comment: You don't need a loop. Simply do `rownames(education1) <- c('a', 'b', ...)`.

Comment: Or even easier `row.names(education1) <- letters[1:6]` (if you have only 6 rows like in your example)

Comment: I'm sorry. What I need to change is colname. And I really want to know how to loop through variables, because I have to perform function on it later, just in the same way.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R objects are copied on assignment, so you are modifying copies of the data.frame's, not the references to the original ones.

In fact, if you do :

```
df <- data.frame(x=1,y=2)
v <- list(df)
names(v[[1]]) <- c('a','b')

> df
  x y
1 1 2

> v
[[1]]
  a b
1 1 2
```

as you can see `df` is not modified.

What you want to do can be accomplished using `get` and `assign` functions, or `eval(parse())` (the latter usually discouraged). e.g. :

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=1,y=2)
df2 <- data.frame(x=3,y=4)
df3 <- data.frame(x=5,y=6)

newnames <- c('a','b')

# using get+assign
for(x in c('df1','df2','df3')){
  # get the object corresponding to name contained in x
  # N.B. tmp is a copy of the original object, not a reference to it
  tmp <- get(x)        
  # replace the col names of tmp
  names(tmp) <- newnames 
  # assign tmp to the variable corresponding to the name contained in x
  assign(x,tmp)      
}

# using eval+parse
for(x in c('df1','df2','df3')){
  # evaluate the expression: names(<text contained in x>) <- name
  eval(parse(text=paste0('names(',x,') <-','newnames')))
}
```

---

BTW, the need to iterate through the environment variables (bad practice), can be avoided from the start by directly saving your data.frame's into a list.
For example :

```
dataframes <- list()
dataframes$df1 <- data.frame(x=1,y=2)
dataframes$df2 <- data.frame(x=3,y=4)
dataframes$df3 <- data.frame(x=5,y=6)

# or if you prefer
# dataframes <- list(df1=data.frame(x=1,y=2),
#                    df2=data.frame(x=3,y=4),
#                    df3=data.frame(x=5,y=6))

newnames <- c('a','b')

# using for loop
for(x in names(dataframes)){
  names(dataframes[[x]]) <- newnames 
}

# using lapply
dataframes <- lapply(dataframes,FUN=function(x) { 
                                        names(x) <- newnames
                                        return(x)
                                    })
```

Comment: Please show them at least that they should put their data.frames in a list, which would enable them to use `lapply`. Right now your answer promotes bad practise.